# HTML5 video offline WITHOUT webserver

Tags: html, video, offline

I'm making a simple zip package demonstration which will have an index.html with a  tag and 3 sources (webm, mp4, ogg). This setup works fine on my server in any browser but I want it to be available offline so someone without an internet connection can view the video locally. I know its a mime type issue and I usually serve this from apache or S3 but I want this available offline without embedding a server in the package.

Here is an example of the page

```
<video preload="none" tabindex="0">
<source src="video/part1.webm" type="video/webm"></source>
<source src="video/part3.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
<source src="video/part2.ogg" type="video/ogg"></source>
</video>
```

and my folder structure is:

index.html
- video
-- part1.webm
-- part2.ogg
-- part3.mp4

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: should work fine - as long as when they unzip the files the paths match what you have given in the HTML source (relative directories) and the browser they are using supports <video>

Comment: You're right, fox and chrome are ok with it but IE 10 doesn't seem to like it what so ever!